# Создание UI для android в kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

При просмотре [этого](https://youtu.be/VU_L2_XGQ9s?t=46m45s) видео увидел интересную штуку, что UI создается не в XML, а в коде. Погуглив я понял что это делается при помощи библиотеки `Anko` и решил попробовать что то сделать.
Результат:

```
class UI(launch: Activity) {


init {
    launch.setContentView(
            launch.UI {
        verticalLayout {
            var cc = 0
            button("Click $cc") {
                onClick {
                    text = "Click ${++cc}"
                }
            }.lparams{
                width = dip(200)
                height = dip(75)
            }
        }
    }.view)
   }
}
```

Посмотрев на свое творение я подумал что можно как то улучшить код, но как это сделать я сейчас не могу понять, поэтому прошу у знатоков совета по этому вопросу.

Comment: что конкретно вы собираетесь улучшить? Вообще Anko та же верстка через xml, только в другом формате - там вы пишите на декларативном языке, здесь в виде кода - результат один и тот же и возможности равные.

Comment: Просто я первый раз попробовал UI написать на Kotline и мне интересно насколько правильно я это сделал?

Answer (score 1):

Anko та же верстка через xml, только в другом формате - там вы пишите на декларативном языке, здесь в виде кода - результат один и тот же и возможности равные.

Вы можете продолжать использовать классическую для Android xml-верстку и при написании программ на Kotlin, Anko лишь альтернативный инструмент, а не обязательное условие разработки UI на Kotlin.

Лично я считаю, что UI должен быть на декларативном языке (XML). Во первых это разделяет бизнес-логику и дизайн на отдельные сущности. Потом xml-верстку можно предварительно оценить в визуальном редакторе и там же доступны все атрибуты виджетов в виде таблицы и вообще работать с ней намного комфортнее, чем с кодом.

Насчет насколько правильно - делаете то же самое, что и в xml-верстке, только пишите в другом формате, вот и вся правильность.

Насчет биндинга - есть такая официальная поддержка биндинга в XML: [Android Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html), инструмент пожалуй помощнее Anko, хотя я, если честно, с Anko особо не разбирался, такие концепции (UI в коде) мне не нравятся